# A Firefox plugin to display the distance between the sides of an element and its parent

Tags: html, firefox, firefox-addon

Does such an add-on exist for Firefox?

[image]

Comment: Not exactly, but Firebug and the Web Developer toolbar give you the x and y positions of the element, and its dimensions. If you're willing to use a calculator, that may work. It should also be possible to do as a Greasemonkey script. What do you need this for?

Comment: As a side comment, downvoting hurts your reputation too.

Comment: -1 because question is unclear: several people have given the same response which is apparently not what the questioner wanted, but questioner has not clarified the question.

Comment: Have you even tried to read the title? Do you know English? Let me know what's not clear about the title and the question and what's ambiguous about it.

Comment: @Bytecode Ninja: Erm... have you even tried to read the comment I left below yesterday, where I explain these things? It's in English and everything :-p

Comment: @Bytecode Ninja: P.S. Being rude to people who are trying to help you - for free - as you have done in a number of comments on this page - is not a very good way of getting a useful answer. Even if the answers you have so far *are* wrong :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's not such a plugin available at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

[**Firebug**](http://getfirebug.com/).

[alt text http://xavierho.com/temp/SOFirebug.jpg](http://xavierho.com/temp/SOFirebug.jpg)

And you will have to do some simple arithmetics, if you mix borders/margins/paddings.

Comment: I think this does not exactly do what the OP wants. Padding is not equal to the distance to the parent element.

Comment: As Pekka has said, Firebug does not have this feature.

Comment: Well, you're welcome to ignore my answer. But you can always measure and find out what it is with the tools available in Firebug. Nonetheless, I edited my answer to explicitly state the necessary calculation if you need to.

Comment: Well I unvoted your answer but it's just not the answer to my question. Of course I can calculate the distance myself but as I've said in the question I want a tool that displays these distances so that I don't have to calculate them myself.

Comment: It seems most other answers are offering the same thing. I'm curious as Pekka, too. What do you need it for?

Answer (score 2):

If you can see the edges in question, there's always [MeasureIt](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/539/). Sometimes I find it quicker than Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

the best addon I can think of is [CSSViewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2104), there is also firebug or web developer toolbar.

you can see more addons in [this top 50 list](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/development/the-best-50-firefox-add-ons-for-web-developers/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link but none of the items listed there do what I am looking for.

Comment: yes there is, nr 2 in that list is Firebug and that will do what you are looking for. look at the screenshot Xavier Ho made.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) can tell you this information: enable it, choose the HTML tab, choose the element you're interested in, then select the layout tab on the right. It shows a diagram quite similar to your artwork above :-)

Comment: Similar, yes, but not equal. As far as I can see, Firebug can't tell the distance of the right hand and bottom sides to the parent borders.

Comment: It can't. Don't confuse padding/margin/border with the distance between an element's boundaries (e.g. its border) to the boundaries of its parent.

Comment: @Bytecode Ninja: in many, many cases they will be the same (or at least, this will give the information required) - think `<span>` inside `<td>` inside `<tr>` inside `<tbody>` inside `<table>`: often only one of these will have nonzero padding/margins. It wasn't clear from your question whether this would be enough or not - you might want to update your question, given the number of people who have interpreted it similarly :-) (You might also want to clarify whether you want to take into account borders, padding, margins of the inside/outside elements!)